# Why can't I add string "<ns4:foo" to a string? Comes out as "<foo"

Tags: javascript, html, xml, tags

Here is what my code looks like:

```
var abc = "";
abc += "<ns4:foo ";
console.log(abc);
```

What gets printed is:

```
<foo
```

What happens to the **ns4:**?

Comment: I get `<ns4:foo ` doing exactly that.

Comment: okay, I don't think that the code is working then. I tried to change the string and it will only go through sometimes. Thanks anyways!

Comment: If that is truly what you see in the console the problem is elsewhere, the code you posted does exactly what you expect it to.